# How to group objects by their name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I receive a response like

```
   [
     {id:1,name:"type1-something"},
     {id:2,name:"something-type2"},
     {id:3,name:"type3-something"},
     {id:4,name:"something-type1"}
   ]
```

and I have an Enum that contains all names from the response

```
enum E{
  E1 = 'type1-something',
  E2 = 'something-type2',
  E3 = 'type3-something',
  E4 = 'something-type1',
}
```

I need to group response by their names.
For example from the response above I need to transform it in

```
{
 "Type1" : [{id:1,name:"type1-something"},{id:4,name:"something-type1"}],
 "Type2" : [{id:2,name:"something-type2"}],
 "Type3" : [{id:3,name:"type3-something"}],
}
```

What approach can be taken? I think of a `map` and a for loop

```
if (object.name == E1 || object.name == E4)
   MAP['Type1'].push(object)
```

But I have over 30 entries in the enum and this will approach will become very big and hard to understand. Obviously I can reduce the amount of code by adding some smaller enums
that will include only their type, but I wonder if there is a more obvious way that I do not see

Comment: do you have other relations? do you have a greater data set to play with?

Comment: Is the criterion always "typeX", or is there more criteria?

Comment: @Teemu it is a key word somewhere in the name, it is always present, but in can be everywhere in the name

Comment: In that case I think you don't need the enum at all, just check if "typeX" is included in the value, ex. using a RegExp.

Comment: Oh I forgot, the name can be "typeX-typeY-something", I know from the beginning what objects I will receive, that is why i have this enum

Comment: Into which group should that be placed?

Comment: in the group typeX-typeY

Comment: Though you've already accepted an answer, take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ew2n97j4/1/). It shows that it's possible to create the result without the enum array, unless a value "typeX-something-typeY" exists too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the type and group by this value.

```js
const
    getType = ({ name }) => name
        .match(/type\d+/g)
        ?.map(s => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1))
        .join('-') || '',
    data = [{ id: 1, name: "type1-something" }, { id: 2, name: "something-type2" }, { id: 3, name: "type3-something" }, { id: 4, name: "something-type1" }, { id: 5, name: "type3-type1-something" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        (r[getType(o)] ??= []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```